# Passing a serialized object to webmethod in .asmx using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

From my aspx.cs(codebehind) i am consuming the webmethod (.asmx)

Now i am trying to pass a GUID from my codebehind as a object to the webmethod.
I could not do it directly as it gives me this error :

**Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.**

So, i tried to create a class

```
[Serializable]
public class Key
{
    public Guid _key; 
    public Guid Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _key;
        }

        set
        {
            _key =  new Guid(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]);
        }
    }
}

public object AuthKey()
    { 
        Key obj = new Key();   
        return obj;
    }

//Calling the webservice like this,

get_list_webservice.return_data objlist = get_list_webservice.GetList(AuthKey());

//WebMethod
 public return_data get_list_webservice(object obj)
        {

}
```

And now, I am using this to pass to the webmethod. But still not working...

What is the problem with this ? I understand that object should be serialized while sending it to webmethod. But where am i doing wrong ? Where to use XMLInclude ?

Comment: Show the code that's "passing" the GUID. Also, are you aware that ASMX is old tech?

Comment: Also, `[Serializable]` is not used by the XML Serializer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Updated the code. Yes I am aware of old tech. But no choice, got to use this now :(

Comment: What is the signature of the `GetList` method? What is the type of the parameter? `object` or `Guid`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders The GetList method uses a class which will return the result as object. Please see the above code (Updated Again). return_data is a class which i use that contains the result and status as members of it

Comment: If its just a GUID that you want to pass to the service, why not use string? And cast this on the server? Or you don't have access to server side code?

Comment: @Mez Above is the example given here. In actual case there are 6 different guids (Keys) i need to pass to the webmethod for some purpose. So i thought of coding all the 6 keys in one class and send that object to webmethod

Answer (score 0):

If the Web Method takes an `object` as a parameter, then you could pass anything as a parameter. You need to tell the code what the possibilities are:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(System.Guid))] 
public return_data get_list_webservice(object obj)
```

Comment: Getting this ERROR : Error 106 Attribute 'XmlInclude' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, struct, method, interface' declarations.

Comment: Then try it on the method.